# SelectInput resettable does not get focus / display validate erros

Tags: typescript, react-admin

The following TSX create a React-Admin 4.8.3 SelectInput with a cross that reset values on click.

```
<ReferenceInput
  label={label}
  reference={reference}
  sort={byTranslatedAscendingNameSort}
  source={source}
>
  <SelectInput
    optionText={`name_${locale}`}
    resettable={true}
    source="id"
    validate={required()}
  />
</ReferenceInput>
```

After clicking on the reset cross, values are reset and focus is not on the component.

No validate errors are display until component get and lose focus.

[Gif example of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJ3Yv.gif)

SelectInput and SimpleForm validate detect that the value is undefined after resetting, so errors object is set and contains values.

But those are not display until component get and lose focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validation strategy is customizable for the form: [Validation Mode](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Validation.html) , here is a description of the strategies: [props mode](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/#mode). Try for example like this:

```
<SimpleForm
  mode="onChange"
  reValidateMode="onChange"
  ...        
>
```